# How do I reliably find fractions and decimals in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript, fractions

Q) I want to be able to parse a string in js and output the parts of the string that are either a number or a fraction.

e.g: `"1.5 litres 1/4 cup"`

**Note:** I've already figured out how to get the whole numbers and decimals from the example string below, but not the fraction representations.

I'm currently using something like this:

```js
const originalString = "1.5 litres 1/4 cup";
var number_regex = /[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g;
var matches = [];
var match;

// FIX - does this ever actually get stuck ?
// replace this with non-while loop from article: http://danburzo.ro/string-extract/
while ((match = number_regex.exec(originalString)) !== null) {
  matches.push({
    original: match[0],
    newVal: ''
  });
}
console.log(matches)
```

Comment: please reopen this - I've added my current code - don't be so quick to judge.

Comment: Your regex does not ever attempt to match the forward slash.... You should try something, at least... It seems you didn't do anything to make that extra match, and just leave it up for us. The downvote button has a tooltip about this...

Comment: Change `\.` to `[.\/]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this to extract each number as an array of strings

```js
const input = `Take 1.5 litres 1/4 cup of sugar
    and 2ml or 2/3 teaspoon or salt
    then take 5 litres of 2.5% vinegar`

const regex = /[+-]?\d+(?:[\.\/]?\d+)?/gm
console.log(
  [...input.matchAll(regex)].map(a => a[0])
)
// returns ["1.5", "1/4", "2", "2/3", "5", "2.5"]
```